# iScroll on textarea

Tags: ipad, iscroll

On iPad app that I have iScoll is applied on divs and it works perfect.

I have a textarea that contains a long text. On desktop we have scroll bar on long textarea but on iPad we don't.

How can I have scroll on textarea?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by detecting textarea's actual height:
textaraElement.scrollHeight

then assign it to textarea height:
textaraElement.style.height = textaraElement.scrollHeight + "px";

By this way textarea is scrollable inside iscroll divs. 
Just notice that you should repeat this and refresh iscroll on ipad orientation change.

If your textarea is editable then on keyup run this line:

textaraElement.style.height = textaraElement.scrollHeight + "px";

and iscroll refresh.

Comment: Could you please show me some jsfiddle with this solution running ? Im stuck with just the same problem